# Is it possible to right-click on a file in Downloads when displayed via dock?

Tags: finder, dock

Is it possible to interact with the files you have in the downloads folder directly via the dock? So think you've downloaded a file, you want to right click and select "open with...". If I click on downloads and have the contents displayed as fan or grid, I cannot right click on the individual files. It's simple but really annoying to have to open downloads folder on Finder just to be able to right click on a file.

I am on Catalina btw